# Get a rank within a category PD

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
{'class' : 'a', 'score' : 10},
{'class' : 'a', 'score' : 30},
{'class' : 'a', 'score' : 20},
{'class' : 'b', 'score' : 15},
{'class' : 'b', 'score' : 25},
{'class' : 'b', 'score' : 35},])

class  score
0     a     10
1     a     30
2     a     20
3     b     15
4     b     25
5     b     35
```

I'm tryng to create a new column `rank` where it is the rank of the value within the class. So the resultant would be:

```
class  score  rank
0     a     10     3
1     a     30     1
2     a     20     2
3     b     15     3
4     b     25     2
5     b     35     1
```

What would be the best way to do so? Using an `apply` or a `pd` native function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the dataframe with the `class` column first, then use [Series.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) to get the rank of the `score` column.

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['class'], sort=False)['score'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Comment: df['rank'] = df.groupby(['class'], sort=False).rank(ascending=False).astype('int')

Comment: @woods can you please post full answer